# How to pass boolean parameter to Oracle procedure C#

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, stored-procedures, ado.net

I have problem to pass boolean parameter to my procedure in Oracle. I get error

```
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
  PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'LOG_ENTRY'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
  PL/SQL: Statement ignored"
```

Procedure  in Oracle:

```
log_entry(p_rqserial in integer,
          p_orig in varchar,
          p_type in char,
          p_objname in varchar,
          p_info in varchar,
          p_text in varchar, p_with_commit boolean)
```

This my code :

```
    cmd = new Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand("Vbank_pkg.vb_log_entry", con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("p_rqserial", OracleDbType.Int32).Value = Log_Serial;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("p_orig", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = "\'" + p_orig + "\'";
    cmd.Parameters.Add("p_type", OracleDbType.Char).Value = "\'" + p_type + "\'";
    cmd.Parameters.Add("p_objname", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = "\'" + p_objname + "\'";
    cmd.Parameters.Add("p_info", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = "\'" + p_info + "\'";
    cmd.Parameters.Add("p_text", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = "\'" + p_text + "\'";
    cmd.Parameters.Add("p_with_commit", OracleDbType.Char).Value =true;
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();//Here error
```

Do any know how to do this? Because I can't find any solution and many people says it's inpossible to pass bool parameter from C# to Oracle but I can't believe there is no way.

Comment: Remove the quotes, that's one of the main benefits to use prepared statements and bind parameters.

Comment: Unbelievable but true: boolean parameters are not supported between C# and Oracle stored procedure. You need to use a Y/N or 0/1 type of parameter instead  :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `BindByName` property of `OracleCommand` as `true` to force the data provider bind these parameters by name and not just for the index. You do not need to pass the `'` as parameters. It is lead with parameters in the `ado.net`.

ODP.NET does not support Boolean data type. Just use `1` or `0` as a `char` value to persist it.

For Sample:

```
cmd = new Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand("Vbank_pkg.vb_log_entry", con);

cmd.BindByName = true;
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

cmd.Parameters.Add("p_rqserial", OracleDbType.Int32).Value = Log_Serial;
cmd.Parameters.Add("p_orig", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = p_orig;
cmd.Parameters.Add("p_type", OracleDbType.Char).Value = p_type;
cmd.Parameters.Add("p_objname", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = p_objname;
cmd.Parameters.Add("p_info", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = p_info;
cmd.Parameters.Add("p_text", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = p_text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("p_with_commit", OracleDbType.Char).Value = "1";

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: I all ready tried this,it is not working.After all time that i spend on this i ask to change the function in Oracle,and chaned the parameter to integer 0-false and 1-true,it is be much faster :)

Comment: But i still be very happy to find another solution.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you, but, unfortunately ODP.NET does not support bool type, so, you have to use 1 or 0.

Comment: When I try using `OracleDbType.Char`, I get the following error: `"ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:\nPLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'REGISTER'\nORA-06550: line 1, column 7:\nPL/SQL: Statement ignored" System.Exception {Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException}`.  I can avoid this in my own stored procedures, but I can't avoid this with Oracle's built in stored procedures without creating "wrappers" to translate.  What is odd is that it worked for me with ODP.NET until I just upgraded from 12c1 to current version 12c2.

Comment: This solution doesn't appear to work in Oracle.ManagedDataAccess v 12.1 either.  Has anyone figured out how to make this work?  I see with gridtrak mentioned, it used to work, but now it doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score -1):

Consider the following procedure as example

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE my_procedure
(
   condition NUMBER,...
```

In C#, add parameter

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@condition", OracleDbType.Char).Value = myObject.isCondition ? 1 : 0;
```