# ORA-06550: wrong number or types of arguments in call to

Tags: c#, oracle

I am trying to call an oracle function in C# but not able to figure out why i keep getting type or argument error. Any help would be appreciated.  I have validated the reference data type and have used to the best of my understanding.

```
FUNCTION VALIDATE_DIFF_PCT_HIER(
         O_error_message          IN OUT  RTK_ERRORS.RTK_TEXT%TYPE,
         I_record_exists          IN      BOOLEAN,
         I_each_diff_pct_x_100    IN      TVC_PMT_DIFF_PCT_HIER.EACH_DIFF_PCT%TYPE,
         I_case_diff_pct_x_100    IN      TVC_PMT_DIFF_PCT_HIER.CASE_DIFF_PCT%TYPE,
         I_pallet_diff_pct_x_100  IN      TVC_PMT_DIFF_PCT_HIER.PALLET_DIFF_PCT%TYPE,
         I_dept                   IN      DEPS.DEPT%TYPE,
         I_class                  IN      CLASS.CLASS%TYPE,
         I_subclass               IN      SUBCLASS.SUBCLASS%TYPE)
```

C# Code.

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("O_error_message", OracleDbType.Varchar2, ParameterDirection.InputOutput).Value = string.Empty;
cmd.Parameters.Add("I_record_exists", OracleDbType.Char, ParameterDirection.Input).Value = "1";
cmd.Parameters.Add("I_each_diff_pct_x_100", OracleDbType.Double, ParameterDirection.Input).Value = 0.04;
cmd.Parameters.Add("I_case_diff_pct_x_100", OracleDbType.Double, ParameterDirection.Input).Value = -0.1;
cmd.Parameters.Add("I_pallet_diff_pct_x_100", OracleDbType.Double, ParameterDirection.Input).Value = -0.1;
cmd.Parameters.Add("I_dept", OracleDbType.Int32, ParameterDirection.Input).Value = row.DeptId;
cmd.Parameters.Add("I_class", OracleDbType.Int32, ParameterDirection.Input).Value = row.ClassId;
cmd.Parameters.Add("I_subclass", OracleDbType.Int32, ParameterDirection.Input).Value = row.SubClassId;
cmd.Parameters.Add("Return_Value", OracleDbType.Char, ParameterDirection.ReturnValue);

conn.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: besides @lad2025's comment, OracleDbType.Char may be problematic for `I_record_exists`

Comment: OracleDBType doesn't have Boolean.

Comment: RTK_ERRORS.RTK_TEXT%TYPE - does refer to the type of the field rtk_text - just from the naming, your are using char but the naming suppose that the return type is not char. Please verify that the field is really char.

Comment: I did check that the filed for RTK_TEXT  is VARCHAR2(255), hence i am using varchar2 for it, but i keep on getting the same error.

Comment: `i_record_exists` is a PL/SQL Boolean, but you are declaring a `Char` parameter for it and setting it to `1`. Unless there is some implicit conversion in `OracleDbType` that's obviously not going to work, because neither `1` nor `'1'` is a PL/SQL Boolean.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass boolean parameter to Oracle procedure C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27919012/how-to-pass-boolean-parameter-to-oracle-procedure-c-sharp)